# Move Title and the Content WYSIWYG editor position

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta, wysiwyg

Right now, the Title is the first thing at the top of the page, then we have next the WYSIWYG Editor.

I would like to add a Custom Meta Box and insert it **before** the title or WYSIWYG editor.
How can I move them around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to put that meta box after the title. There is a hook called `edit_form_after_title`. If you [look at the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L379) there is no hook earlier than that that isn't much too early-- outside of the `<form` tag. The following does move that box to the location after the title...

```
function generic_box() {
  remove_meta_box('postcustom',null,'core');
  add_meta_box('postcustomv2', __('Custom Fields'), 'post_custom_meta_box', 'post', 'after_title');
}
add_action('do_meta_boxes','generic_box',100);

function add_box_after_title() {
  global $post_type, $post;
  do_meta_boxes($post_type, 'after_title', $post);
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_box_after_title' );
```

... but there is a slight issue. I can't seem to get the box to remove and then add it back with the same ID. I've added it back as `postcustomv2` but it is the same callback. This results in a slight formatting glitch but it seems to work.

## Edit:

I thought of a way to cheat... a lot. No guarantees of functionality with this one.

```
function title_cheat() { 
  global $post; ?>
  <div id="titlewrap">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" id="title-prompt-text" for="title"><?php echo apply_filters( 'enter_title_here', __( 'Enter title here' ), $post ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="<?php echo esc_attr( htmlspecialchars( $post->post_title ) ); ?>" id="title" autocomplete="off" />
 </div><?php
}

function generic_box() {
  remove_meta_box('postcustom',null,'core');
  remove_post_type_support('post','title');   
  add_meta_box('postcustomv2', __('Custom Fields'), 'post_custom_meta_box', 'post', 'after_title');
  add_meta_box(
    'titlediv', // id, used as the html id att
    __( 'Title' ), // meta box title
    'title_cheat', // callback function, spits out the content
    'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
    'after_title', // context, where on the screen
    'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
  );
}
add_action('do_meta_boxes','generic_box',100);

function add_box_after_title() {
  global $post_type, $post;
  do_meta_boxes($post_type, 'after_title', $post);
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_box_after_title' );
```

If you  remove post type support for the "title" the title box disappears, and you can then add it back where you want.

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.