# Make title field multiline in the add new custom post page?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have a custom post type named "news". The title field holds the raw news and i added another custom field that holds the published news.
The published news field is a text area so i can use enter button when editing. Is there a way to make the title field behave like that, to edit in multiline?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using the title for chunks of content. That title is used for things like generating `URL`s, for example, and it could be used for all kinds of things by the theme and plugins. That is almost certainly going to cause trouble.

I'd suggest you [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) without 'title' support and [create a custom meta box for you "raw news"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), or just use the title for it is meant for-- a title.

To answer the question directly though, [the markup that generates the title section is hard-coded](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L346). You can't alter it.

## Related:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105786/21376