# How to hook something before edit_form_title?

Tags: metabox, hooks

It's amazing to use the [`edit_form_after_title`](https://www.google.com/search?&q=edit_form_after_title) hook to enqueue something just below the post editor's title field. But there is nothing opposite to this like: *`edit_form_before_title`*. Searching over the Internet, found [the trac treasure](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24861) with a solution saying:

> *Add an `edit_form_top` hook to the post edit form.*

That's pretty! But that's not exactly what I's looking for. That's taking the whole top part of the form, not behaving like the Title field on the editor.
[image: edit_form_top hook renders like this]

Is there any solution/hook I can use so that the thing I'm hooking looks exactly like the Title field (not taking the whole top part of the form, but renders on the left part only.)?

#### EDIT

And also, if I use `edit_form_top` then if I use any input field to add meta_value to the post, then it'll be failed because `edit_form_top` adds the *thing* **outside the form**.

SPECIFICALLY, I need to add a custom input field to add meta_value to the post. I don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: Not per PHP, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move Title and the Content WYSIWYG editor position](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105772/move-title-and-the-content-wysiwyg-editor-position)